# Restoring deleted certificates from AWS IOT

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I accidentally deleted certificates from AWS IoT Core. These certificates are used by our provisioning templates/policies. I do have the physical certificates and private/public keys, however, I'm unable to find a way to re-upload these certificates back to AWS IOT. Is it possible?

I tried "Registering" these certificates, but it complains that the certificates are invalid. These certificates were generated by Amazon CA.